# Create a table from the existing table, only with few columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with `info` database as name. And in it I have a table named `boys` which contains `id, first_name, last_name, status, points, profession`.

Now I want to create a new table inside of `info` DB with `boys_info` table name and the columns `status, point, profession`.

How can I achieve this? I use MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE boys_info AS
SELECT status, point, profession
FROM boys
```